# razor payment giving No appropriate payment method found error

Tags: android, razorpay

so I'm implementing this simple razor payment integration. but it's giving me a "No appropriate payment method found" error. I tried choosing the payment options form before that didn't work either.

```
val razorpay = RazorpayClient("my key", "my secret key")
       val orderRequest = JSONObject()
       orderRequest.put("amount", 50000); // amount in the smallest currency unit
       orderRequest.put("currency", "INR");
       orderRequest.put("receipt", "order_rcptid_11")
       try {
           val order: Order = razorpay.Orders.create(orderRequest)
           Timber.d("order : $order")
           startPayment(order)
       } catch (e: RazorpayException) {
           Timber.e(e)
       } 
private fun startPayment(order: Order) {
       val checkout = Checkout()

       checkout.setKeyID("my key my secret key")
       /*
       *  You need to pass current activity in order to let Razorpay create CheckoutActivity
       * */
       val activity: Activity = this
       try {
           checkout.open(activity, order.toJson())
       } catch (e: Exception) {
           Toast.makeText(activity, "Error in payment: " + e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           e.printStackTrace()
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was my mistake

`checkout.setKeyID("my key my secret key")`

I needed to provide only "my key" here.
the method name literally saying that "setKeyID".

Answer (score 4):

Some times key is not working use another test key of other project

checkout.setKeyID("rzp_test_--------")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. Go to Razorpay account. Where you found payment methods and tap the request buttons which payment methods do you want to apply.
Issue which was fixed payment method activate by Razor pay.
"OOPS!Somthing went wrong.
No appropriate payment method found"