# How to solve "No appropriate payment method found" in razor payment test mode?

Tags: php, codeigniter, razorpay

Our Codeigniter website is integrated with Razorpay, and I'd like to test payment using Razorpay's test mode.

**Steps I followed :**

1. Enabled test mode from Razor pay website.
2. Changed razor api key in config.php as below:

   ```
    $razor_api_key = "rzp_test_xxxxxxxxx";
   ```

3 . Also edited api key in index.php

```
    $api = new Api("rzp_test_xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

When I go to payment, the page shows an error: "No appropriate payment method found."

Comment: Hey you can visit here same error was found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68979937/razor-payment-giving-no-appropriate-payment-method-found-error

Comment: Where can I find setKeyID? I mean, which page

Comment: Also, the code in your example differs slightly from mine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey can you refer the below example how the key is used by the project setup

https://junaidsshaikh.medium.com/razorpay-payment-gateway-integration-using-codeigniter-3-7bfc22e157aa

For this type of error, You are most likely using an incorrect Razorpay Key. try the below solution:

**Reasons**

1. Using the test key for live or vice versa in Razorpay environments.
2. Using a totally different Key that you may have generated for a totally different project

**Some Approaches to review the issue**

1. If you need the keys for the TEST environment, make sure that in Razorpay Dashboard Header, you have selected TEST mode.
2. Visit here https://dashboard.razorpay.com/app/keys and grab the Key Id.

Comment: The website is already working for live payment mode. For some purpose, I want to check the payment in test mode.